# Application crashes when switching from one method to another in android

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

Whenever `onCreate` completes, the application crashes while going to another method. In debug it shows `icicle=null`: why?

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);
     result =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     ((Button)findViewById(R.id.take_picture)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
     -------------
       ----------------
       ------------------
   }
       @override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(TAKE_PICTURE_CODE == requestCode){
            processCameraImage(data);
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Log Cat:**

```
04-17 18:00:30.819: D/dalvikvm(15842): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1592K (22183), 37% free 3060K/4852K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
04-17 18:00:30.851: D/AndroidRuntime(15842): Shutting down VM
04-17 18:00:30.851: W/dalvikvm(15842): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e789a8)
04-17 18:00:30.851: W/dalvikvm(15842): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
04-17 18:00:30.851: W/System.err(15842): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 18:00:30.851: W/System.err(15842):    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity$3$1.run(FdActivity.java:132)
04-17 18:00:30.851: W/System.err(15842):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
04-17 18:00:30.852: W/System.err(15842):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 18:00:30.853: W/dalvikvm(15842): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity$3$1.run(FdActivity.java:132)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
04-17 18:00:30.855: E/AndroidRuntime(15842):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 18:00:30.927: I/Process(15842): Sending signal. PID: 15842 SIG: 9
```

Comment: is it going from one method to another or one activity to another? Title and description both contradict each other, please update properly and please add log cat trace.

Comment: Do all the specific id's exist? Are all required activities included in the manifest file? Seeing the id "take_picture", have you set the right permission(s)?

Comment: you better post the whole code ad logcat

Comment: When I am switching from one method to another, and the layout also changes

Comment: I have posted logcat as well

Comment: Your onCreate looks absolutely fine. 
You not posted code from where which method calls. Provide that method call code.

Comment: 'icicle' parameter will always return null, if there is no previously-saved state. You can override 'onSavedInstance' method to save your current state or any value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the layout `R.layout.face_detect_surface_view` contains a `Button` type view with id `R.id.take_picture`. Seems like a missing View.